# How can i finish a translation file

Tags: localisation

I have a Romanian translation witch is incomplete. How can i finish it? How to edit that lang file? I tried to open that cvs file but i'm clueless. It is what i have to do or there's other steps in order to finish the translation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The translation csv structure is simple.
Each line is like this:

```
"Key here","Translation here"
```

In order to have a complete translation of a module file, you should get that file from the `en_US` locale and translate the second column.
If you already have a partial translation file, just compare the first column of that file with the first column of the `en_US` locale file. This way you can identify what's missing in your `ro_RO` locale.
a simple script that parses the 2 csv files should do it.
You can also use [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool). It allows you (among others) to generate the files for a specific locale by parsing the module files and then it can help you identify the untranslated texts.